# How to define production scope for Angular / Typescript in IntelliJ's project overview

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, ide

I'm currently working on an Angular (Typescript) project. IntelliJ offers different scopes for a project in the project menu:

[image]

The ***Tests*** scope works just fine. When i select it only ***spec.ts*** files are shown. Unfortunately the production scope doen't work, the IDE outputs *No files in the current scope*. I would expect it to only show **ts**-files leaving out the test files.

Does anyone know how i can configure my Intellij to work the expected way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try marking your `src` folder as **Sources Root** (**Mark Directory as/Sources Root**)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If anyone wonders where to find that option: File -> Project Structure -> Modules